# Weird IE8 problem when using .animate({'height':'toggle'})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

Check out http://wouter.howafarms.com/faq

The goal is to have answers be expanded on click.
As you'll see this works  perfectly in all browsers except for ie8.

I've tried various animation effects .slideDown(), .toggle() to no avail.  They always work in Firefox, Chrome and even IE7, but never in IE8.  What in the heck might be causing it.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#faq-list li").addClass('inactive');
$("#faq-list li").first('.inactive').toggleClass('inactive');
$("#faq-list li h2").toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.answer').animate({'height': 'toggle'},{queue:true,duration:300})
        $(this).toggleClass('inactive')
    } ,
    function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.answer').animate({'height': 'toggle'},{queue:true,duration:300})
        $(this).toggleClass('inactive')
    })
```

})

Comment: In IE8 it correctly collapses all the answers.  That's when things break.  The idea is to click the question and it would slideDown or toggle the answer.  It does this great in other browsers, but for some reason IE8 shows a quick down-up and never reveals the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not sure why, but `display:inline` on your h2 element (the question) is why the collapse isn't working right in ie8.  remove that and you are fine.  just have to restyle the "q" so it lines up

Answer (score 1):

Just tried... yeah it is a bit odd.. maybe IE8's having a stroke with its height calculation.

Maybe try slideDown/slideUp instead of .animate({'height': 'toggle'} in your toggle?

Also, you can write the first two lines:

```
$("#faq-list li").addClass('inactive');
$("#faq-list li").first('.inactive').toggleClass('inactive');
```

as

```
$("#faq-list li:not(:first)").addClass('inactive');
```

Comment: Good call!  Although slideDown/slideUp has the same problem.